# Bootstrap column ordering Firefox issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 3 columns in my app, two thin side columns, and a thicker one in the middle.
In mobile view, I want the middle one to be on top, so I used the push-pull method. This works perfectly.

In the large view, I want all three columns to be the same height, regardless of content, so I used the table/table-cell display method. This works fine too, but prevents the push-pull in FireFox.

I have a bootply illustrating my problem:
http://www.bootply.com/vHjyM1EtYl

Run that in IE, FF & Chrome. You'll see that in FF the "Mid" column is on the left. Comment out the "height" classes and see that it gets pulled to the correct locations again.

Comment: The columns aren't equally high in Chrome either, although they do appear in the correct order.

Comment: Dreamonic, I think you should have a look at it again, they are all exactly the same height in all browsers.

Comment: No, they're not. This is how I see them when looking at your Bootply: http://i.imgur.com/4OsB4VA.png

Comment: Ah, but I just noticed that may occur because of your media query; my browser window doesn't have a width of 1200+px.

Comment: Have you found a decent solution to this problem? It's killing me

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap push and pull uses float. By setting it to none, you eliminate the ability to push or pull. You do not need `float: none` if you add the height you want to that class.

[Updated Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/CGDUWFjV36)

```
.col-md-height {
    display: table-cell;
    /*float: none;*/
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 300px;
}
```

EDIT: For dynamic height you can use jQuery instead of `float: none`. [New Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/ncwBTLDdpp)

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if($(window).width() >= 1200) {
        $('.col-md-height').css('height', $('.container-md-height').height());
  } else {
        $('.col-md-height').css('height', 'auto');
  }
});
```

EDIT #2: For a CSS only solution, you can add a large negative margin-bottom and an equivalent padding-bottom to the 3 columns and then set the container's overflow to hidden. If you do it this way you will not need to use table or table-cell displays.

[CSS Only Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/ynJodRJcPK)

```
.col-md-height {
    margin-bottom: -2000px;
    padding-bottom: 2000px;
}
.container-md-height {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I'm aware that its the "float" attribute causing issues. I just added the height for the middle element as an example, the height of all 3 columns are dynamic. There is no telling which will be higher in each of the apps pages. So I can't set the height explicitly

Comment: I didn't realize that based on your question. I updated my answer.

Comment: Isn't there a CSS only method of using this when having a dynamic height?

Comment: @MiguelStevens I have updated my answer to include a CSS only solution.